# Firestore no responde cuando intento agregar una colección

Tags: firebase, react-native, firestore

tengo un problema con firebase cuando intento agregar datos a mi base de datos firestore. nunca responde quedo esperando y no falla ni nada, solamente no responde y nunca pasa de la ejecución del `addDoc`
este es mi codigo de configuración. estoy usando react native

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import  { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIza...Z3NI",
  authDomain: "la...firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "l...e3",
  storageBucket: "l...ot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "94...445",
  appId: "1:94...47"
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
export const FIRESTORE_DB = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);
```

y esta la forma en la que intento crear la colección implícitamente:

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, "users"), {
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
  });
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

es justo la forma en la que se menciona en la documentación de firebase. Alguien sabe que me hace falta o en que puedo estar confundido?

Comment: Hola. ¿A qué te refiere con que *nunca responde*? ¿Has revisado la colección `users` en Firebase y no hay datos creados?

Comment: No agrega datos en firebase y tampoco da error es decir addDoc no retorna una respuesta y tampoco manda al catch... solo no pasa nada

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar hace unas semanas, al final resultó ser que sobrepasé el limite de uso de Firebase Firestore de manera gratuita. Comprueba eso desde la consola, en la pestaña de "Uso".

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: en realidad tengo un único registro en firestore  y mi factura sigue siendo de $0.00 y desde la consola google cloud firestore si me permite crear los registros. el problema se da cuando intento hacerlo desde mi proyecto... si me es posible usar firebase auth pero al momento de usar firestore no funciona

Answer (score 0):

A mí me parece que según el código publicado, el `try-catch` statement no está siendo ejecutado. Usualmente cuando invocas algún REST request (en esta caso, un POST request) se hace bajo demanda y no por defecto, porque sino crearías un nuevo documento cada vez que montas la aplicación. Asumo que esta es la razón por la que nada ocurre en la consola, ni en la base de datos de Firestore. Para solucionar esto, podrías envolver ese `try catch` en una función como la siguiente:

```javascript
  const addNewUser = () => {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, "users"), {
        first: "Ada",
        last: "Lovelace",
        born: 1815
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log("New user data: ", response.data());
      };
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    } 
  }
```

Luego puedes crear algún botón en tu UI para ejecutar esta acción, claro que aquí sería ideal envolver esa acción en un `useCallback`, pero eso está fuera de scope:

```javascript
<button onClick={addNewUser}>Create new fake user</button>
```

Ahora, si le das click a ese botón, deberías poder observar los logs en tu consola y el usuario en Firestore (en la sección de authentication y bajo la nueva colección de `users`).